# How to change the size of the Legend created using Epilog?

Tags: plotting, legending, fonts

Consider following example.

```
  Table[Sin[\[Alpha] x], {\[Alpha], {0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .45}}]], {x, \
-\[Pi], \[Pi]}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Gray, Cyan, Magenta, Brown}, 
 PlotRange -> {-3, 5}, 
 Epilog -> 
  Inset[Framed[
    Column[{LineLegend[{Blue}, {"    \[Alpha]=0"}], 
      LineLegend[{Red}, {"    \[Alpha]=.1"}], 
      LineLegend[{Gray}, {"    \[Alpha]=.2"}], 
      LineLegend[{Cyan}, {"    \[Alpha]=.3"}], 
      LineLegend[{Magenta}, {"    \[Alpha]=.4"}], 
      LineLegend[{Brown}, {"    \[Alpha]=.45"}]}], 
    RoundingRadius -> 4], Scaled[{.5, 0.55}]]]
```

I would like to know how to make the font of the legend bigger or smaller.

Answer (score 4):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

colors = {Blue, Red, Gray, Cyan, Magenta, Brown};
values = {0, .1, .2, .3, .4, .45};

Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[α x], {α, values}],{x, -π, π},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotRange -> {-3, 5},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 Epilog -> Inset[LineLegend[colors,
    Style[StringForm["α=``", ToString[#]], 8] & /@ values,
    LegendFunction ->
     (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, FrameStyle -> Gray] &)],
   Scaled[{.6, 0.7}]]]
```

[image]

Or using [`PlotLegends`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotLegends.html)

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[α x], {α, values}],
 {x, -π, π},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotRange -> {-3, 5},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Style[StringForm["α=``", ToString[#]], 8] & /@
     values,
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
    LegendFunction ->
     (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, FrameStyle -> Gray] &)],
   Scaled[{.6, 0.7}]]]
```

[image]

Or using [`LegendLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LegendLabel.html) and avoiding all the redundant `α=`

```
Plot[Evaluate@Table[Sin[α x], {α, values}], {x, -π, π},
 PlotStyle -> colors,
 PlotRange -> {-3, 5},
 ImageSize -> 500,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   LineLegend[Style[#, 8] & /@ values,
    LegendLayout -> {"Column", 1},
    LegendFunction ->
     (Framed[#, RoundingRadius -> 4, FrameStyle -> Gray] &),
    LegendLabel -> α],
   Scaled[{.6, 0.7}]]]
```

[image]